# none of this v. none of these

Tags: phrase-usage

> His blood glucose was dangerously high at 288 mg/dl (normal levels are
> below 100), and his cholesterol was 207 mg/dl (normal values are below
> 200). *None of this* was good.

Why is it not "none of these"? The author is American; so do Americans use "none of these" less often? (just guessing!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is correct. Here, *this* doesn't directly refer to the preceding list of items. You can casually think of it as short for *this stuff*, *this information* or *this news*. There is an implicit aggregation of the listed items into a singular whole.

The plural version, "none of these were good," would also be acceptable, although since only two items are listed, "neither of these" would be a better fit.